# Exclude div from css selector

Tags: python, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select only text that is not inside the div element. In this case I want to exclude the div with class `bbCodeBlock`. How can I do that? The idea is exclude the citation.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/14snvd3e/2/)

```
<li id="post-6062713">
  <div class="uix_message ">
    <div class="messageInfo">
      <div class="messageContent">
        <article>
          <blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer">
            <div class="bbCodeBlock bbCodeQuote">
              <aside>
                <div class="attribution type">user said:
                  <a href="#" class="AttributionLink">↑</a>
                </div>
                <blockquote class="quoteContainer">
                  <div class="quote">text to ignore</div>
                </blockquote>
              </aside>
            </div>
            text to change color
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="bbCodeBlock bbCodeQuote">
              <aside>
                <div class="attribution type">user said:
                  <a href="#" class="AttributionLink">↑</a>
                </div>
                <blockquote class="quoteContainer">
                  <div class="quote">text to ignore</div>
                </blockquote>
              </aside>
            </div>
            text to change color
            <div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
          </blockquote>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

This is a basic demo to replicate with scrappy because I need to exclude the quotes, so I am looking for a one line selector to apply to something like

```
'text': quote.css('article blockquote').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after comment:

I just realized that the content which you want to be affected is not *inside* a `div`, but at the same level as the `div` with class `.bbCodeBlock`, i.e direct  content of the `blockquote` element.

Therefore you need to use two selectors/rules, one to set the color for `blockquote`, the other to exclude those children `div` elements of `blockquote` which have the `.bbCodeBlock` class :

```css
article blockquote {
  color: red;
}
article blockquote div:not(.bbCodeBlock) {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<li id="post-6062713">
  <div class="uix_message ">
    <div class="messageInfo">
      <div class="messageContent">
        <article>
          <blockquote class="messageText SelectQuoteContainer">
            <div class="bbCodeBlock bbCodeQuote">
              <aside>
                <div class="attribution type">user said:
                  <a href="#" class="AttributionLink">↑</a>
                </div>
                <blockquote class="quoteContainer">
                  <div class="quote">text to ignore</div>
                </blockquote>
              </aside>
            </div>
            text to change color
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="bbCodeBlock bbCodeQuote">
              <aside>
                <div class="attribution type">user said:
                  <a href="#" class="AttributionLink">↑</a>
                </div>
                <blockquote class="quoteContainer">
                  <div class="quote">text to ignore</div>
                </blockquote>
              </aside>
            </div>
            text to change color
            <div class="messageTextEndMarker">&nbsp;</div>
          </blockquote>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: please not my changed answer

Comment: sorry but this wont work for me, since this is a basic example to replicate when crawling. I need to exclude the initial quote to avoid duplicate text.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "initial quote": You want to exclude all `blockquote`s that contain a DIV with that class, or what?

Comment: FWIW: My snippet does exactly what you are asking for in your question. If that's not what you want, you need to rephrase your question and the code you provided.

Comment: So you want to hide the "text to change color" text? That's not possible with CSS alone. You'd need to wrap it in `span` tags that you apply a class to which you use as a selector for `display: none` (or use Javascript)